# i want to find the location of a number in a matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix lets say

```
x =
 2     2     3
 4     3     2
 6     4     8
```

now I want to get the location of a number 4.
I want `ans` like this :

```
ans=(2,1) (3,2)
```

as these are the locations for 4 in matrix.

Answer (score 14):

Use [`find`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html):

```
[i,j] = find(x == 4)
```

Answer (score 1):

ismember will return an array of 1 or 0 depending on if the cell value there is or isn't the value you're searching for:

```
octave:9> x
x =

   2   2   3
   4   3   2
   6   4   8

octave:10> ismember(x,4)
ans =

   0
   1
   0
   0
   0
   1
   0
   0
   0
```

And then you can use find and ind2sub to get the array indicies of the 1s:

```
octave:11> [i,j] = ind2sub(size(x),find(ismember(x,4)))
i =

   2
   3

j =

   1
   2
```

So that the indicies are (2,1) and (3,2).

Comment: Actually, I guess you can even skip the ismember bit and just use find: [i,j] = ind2sub(size(x),find(x==4))